# I can not update a record with fluent nhibernate 3 and map with generatedby.assigned generator

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-update, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a design with fluent n hibernate, I use nhibernate linq to query the database. The app use a domain driver architecture. The database is MSSQL 2012. I don't have problem to insert, update or delete with any table except the case of one table that use ID without seed identity. then I need to use in the map the following:

```
 public class SySchoolLogoMap : ClassMap<SySchoolLogo>
    {
        public SySchoolLogoMap()
        {
            ReadOnly();

            Table("SySchoolLogo");

            Id(x => x.ID).Column("ImgId").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
            Map(x => x.ContentType).Column("ContentType").Nullable();
            Map(x => x.ImagenBytes).Column("Image").Not.Nullable().Length(50000);
            Map(x => x.ImgLenth).Column("ImgLen").Nullable();
            Map(x => x.ImageFile).Column("imgFile").Nullable();
            Map(x => x.OfficialUse).Column("OfficialUse").Nullable();
            Map(x => x.ImageCode).Column("ImageCode").Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Description).Column("Description").Nullable();
        }
}
```

The domain is as following:

```
 public class SySchoolLogo : DomainEntityWithTypedID<int>
{
  ... abbreviate
}
```

The base DomainEntityWithTypedID
has only a ID integer that is used as Table primary key.

The update operation is using nhibernate link, I I am sure that the service is called and executed.

The update service is the following:

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage UpdateLogo([FromBody]SchoolLogoOutputModel logodata)
        {
            try
            {
                var logo = repository.Get<SySchoolLogo>(logodata.ID);
                if (logo == null)
                {
                    throw new HttpBadRequestResponseException("The Image does not exists or was erased in server.");
                }
               logo.UpdateLogo(logodata.Description, logodata.ImageCode, logodata.OfficialUse);

                repository.SaveAndFlush(logo);
                 return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            } //catch ignored to abbreviate.
```

I had debugged the procedure and I am sure that the operation of Save was executed, also I tried with Update, Merge and all flush variant. The operation return as OK, but the database is not updated.
I am missing something, but I can not find what is, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are using [5.1.3. class](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class) mapping:

```
<class
    ...
    mutable="true|false"                          (4)
    ...
```

> (4)   mutable *(optional, defaults to true)*: Specifies that instances of the class are (not) mutable.

which is the above mapping in fluent:

```
public SySchoolLogoMap()
{
    ReadOnly(); // mutable="false"
```

And that would be the reason why NHiberante correctly does **NOT** execute any UPDATE...

Comment: Ohh Man, I was blind, of course, I tested and now work perfectly, thanks for the explanation. + 1 for the extra explanation.

Comment: Great to see that ;) enjoy NHibernate